# Dar preferencia a igualdade maior, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu possuo uma tabela com uma coluna chamada `X` nela eu insiro valores separados por virgula, por exemplo: `1,2,3,4,5`.

Uso esta query para captar determinado row.

`SELECT * FROM 'x' WHERE CONCAT(',',x,',') LIKE '%,1,2,%'`

Eu queria adaptar esta query para dar preferencia aos rows que tiverem menos diferença. por exemplo, tenho rows desta forma:

1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9[..]

1,2,3,8,91

3,4,5,1

1,2

Quando eu jogo a query ele me mostra todos os rows, por que todos eles contem o `1,2` no entando eu queria que ele desse preferencia aos rows cujo a diferença é menor ou seja ele me mostraria nessa ordem:

1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9[..] - Terceiro

1,2,3,8,91 - Segundo

3,4,5,1 - Quarto

1,2 - Primeiro

Comment: Talvez haja algum truque para resolver o problema, mas acredito que você deveria usar uma tabela de relacionamento em vez de gravar uma lista de números como string.

Comment: o que você quer dizer com `CONCAT(',',x,',')` no `WHERE`?

Comment: 3,4,5,1 nem deveria vir no result !? Não entendi também a tal "diferença" , como disse o @bfavaretto normalizar a tabela tamvez venha a facilitar as coisas.

Comment: @Mateus Isso aí já é um truque para selecionar linhas que contenham determinado número na tal lista.

Comment: informando a própria coluna no `CONCAT`? No `FROM` ele colocou a tabela `'x'` e no `WHERE` tem a coluna `x`, são coisas diferentes?

Comment: No `WHERE` o `x` dele quer dizer qualquer número (acho) @Mateus.

Comment: @bfavaretto nao poderei relacionar pois estes podem ser inseridos de forma randomica.

Comment: @Mateus sao coisas distintas, porem possuem o mesmo nome.

Comment: @user3163662, tentei responder conforme entendi, pode ser que realmente não seja a solução ideal, mas é uma alternativa, já que você disse que não teria como fazer por relacionamento e as informações que temos são poucas para saber se tem como ou não!

Answer (score 1):

> **Nota:** dependendo da quantidade de registros e do tamanho da coluna, provavelmente o desempenho com a *query* não será bom.

Uma maneira de mostrar a menor diferença é considerando a quantidade de caracteres das linhas retornadas, quanto menor for a quantidade de carecteres, menor será a diferença do termo procurado. Para fazer essa verificação você pode utilizar a função [CHAR_LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) como o exemplo abaixo:

```
select 
  [SuasColunas]
from 
  [NomeDaTabela] 
where 
  [NomeDaColuna] like '%1,2%' 
order by 
  char_length([NomeDaColuna])
```

Você pode ver funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebef1/2).